# How to get a list of the corresponding calendar weeks of a specific month (for example of december) in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I only have the month specification in words "december" or as a number "12". Now I want to get the corresponding calender weeks in a list. For december 2022 it should be 48,49,50,51 and 52.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

`=LAMBDA(aix,UNIQUE(FILTER(WEEKNUM(aix,21),MONTH(aix)=12)))(SEQUENCE(365,1,DATE(2022,1,1),1))`

Comment: Thank you again :) When I use your formula it works but it skips the first week "1". I only get 52,2,3,4,5. Why?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/kAjWdhe.png tested for couple of years (Month=1) and I cant seem to recreate the issue. Is there something specific I should be looking at?!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(WEEKNUM(SEQUENCE(DAY(
 EOMONTH("1/"&MONTH(B96&1), )), 1, "1/"&MONTH(B96&1)))))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(ISOWEEKNUM(SEQUENCE(DAY(
 EOMONTH("1/"&MONTH(B96&1), )), 1, "1/"&MONTH(B96&1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Where I define the year in your second formula?

Comment: @johny (current) year is automatically added. you can manually force another year as: `=INDEX(UNIQUE(ISOWEEKNUM(SEQUENCE(DAY(
 EOMONTH("1/"&MONTH(B96&1)&"/2001", )), 1, "1/"&MONTH(B96&1)&"/2001"))))`